# Trouble Understanding Combinatorics Identity for Number of Flips

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is my first post on Mathematics StackExchange (and my first time using LaTeX), so I apologize if my question is a little difficult to read.

I am taking an introductory course on probability theory, and came across a problem concerning the number of flips of a coin to reach the desired number of heads:

*What is the probability that it takes 10 or more flips of a coin to get three heads?*

The probability of *n* flips is given by $\binom{n-1}{2}$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$ , and I seem not to understand exactly why.  I understand that to get the desired answer, you use the complement:

$1-$$\sum_{n=3}^9$$\binom{n-1}{2}$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$

However, the initial combination, I do not.

Again, this is my first post, so I am sorry if I did not ask my question correctly.  Any and all help would be much appreciated!  Thanks everyone!

Comment: An easier approach: The probability that it takes 10 or more flips of a coin to get three heads is the probability that within the first nine flips there are a total of exactly zero, exactly one, or exactly two heads.

Comment: As for the probability that it takes exactly $n$ flips to get three heads, within the first $n-1$ flips, two of them must be heads and the rest must be tails, followed by the $n$'th flip must be heads.  Pick a specific arrangement of the heads/tails such that there are two heads in the first $n-1$ and the $n$'th is a head.  The probability of that specific arrangement occurring is $\frac{1}{2^n}$, giving the result you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of any single outcome of $9$ coin flips is $(\frac{1}{2})^9$ because for a tail or a head the probability is the same, $\frac{1}{2}$. So the probability of getting $2$ heads is $(\frac{1}{2})^9$ times the number of ways of getting $2$ heads in a series of $9$ flips. This is $^9C_2$ = 36. So the answer is $36\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^9 = .0703125$. We know that if we only get $2$ heads in the first $9$ flips, we are guaranteed to take $10$ or more flips to get $3$ heads.

Update: Getting zero heads with seven flips and one head with eight flips will also guarantee ten or more flips to get three heads.

$P(3H\ge 10) = \ ^9C_2\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^9 + 8\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^8 + (\frac{1}{2})^7$

$= .0703125 + .03125 + .0078125$

$= .109375$

Comment: You have neglected to take into consideration what happens when we get zero or only one head in the first nine flips.  Having exactly two heads in the first nine flips does indeed imply that it takes ten or more flips for the third head to have appeared, however the reverse implication is invalid.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for pointing that out.